# C++ equivalent of Python dictionaries

Tags: python, c++

I'm currently making a tic-tac-toe program with AI and i'm having a bit of a trouble translating this line of code (python) :

```
RANKS = dict([(4,3),                       # center  = 3
              (0,2),(2,2),(6,2),(8,2),     # corners = 2
              (1,1),(3,1),(5,1),(7,1)])    # sides   = 1
```

into C++

any suggestions?

Comment: You're more likely to get useful help if you provide some context of `RANKS` being used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Translating python dictionary to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842941/translating-python-dictionary-to-c)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The closest match in C++ would be an [`std::unordered_map<int, int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). This is a hash table mapping `int` keys to `int` values.

```
#include <unordered_map>


std::unordered_map<int, int> RANKS = {
        { 4, 3 },
        { 0, 2 }, { 2, 2 }, { 6, 2 }, { 8, 2 },
        { 1, 1 }, { 3, 1 }, { 5, 1 }, { 7, 1 }
};
```

You can access elements using `operator[]`, for example

```
std::cout << RANKS[0] << std::endl; // prints "2"
```

Note that the C++ standard library also has the [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) class template, which allows you to create a similar but *ordered* look-up table `std::map<int, int>`, with logarithmic look-up and insertion complexity. But python `dict`s are hash tables, so `unordered_map` is a closer match in terms of behaviour.

Comment: will it make any difference if i used map instead?

Comment: @JennyCalisay In this case, the main difference is time complexity. `std::map` is a self-balancing binary search tree, and `std::unordered_map` is a hash table. Look-up is O(log N) vs )(1) respectively, but if you care about performance you should profile code using both.

Comment: While this answer was correct in 2014, future readers should note that that since Python 3.6, `dict` are *insertion ordered* (cf. [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6#answer-39980744)). Thus, since 2017, `std::map` is probably the best answer.

Comment: @scūriolusgodo point. Unfortunately, the ordering is not the same, as `std::map` orders by key, not insertion. I will add a clarification later.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a map or unordered_map for this (and they'd work fine) but given that your keys are a dense set of integers (I.e. all the integers from 0 to N) there are better choices.

I'd probably use an `std::array` instead. It would look something like this:

```
std::array <char, 9> vals = { 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2 };
```

This gives pretty much the same syntax and observable behavior, but will typically save quite a bit of memory and probably CPU time as well.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ this would be a `std::unordered_map`

```
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<int, int> dict
{
    {
        { 4, 3 },
        { 0, 2 }, { 2, 2 }, { 6, 2 }, { 8, 2 },
        { 1, 1 }, { 3, 1 }, { 5, 1 }, { 7, 1 }
    }
};
```

Comment: More like an `unordered_map`, no?

Comment: is it okay if i used mapping on this ?

Comment: Correct, it's `unordered_map` and not `map`

Comment: @juanchopanza Yup, you're right. When you noted that i noticed the first element of each pair is actually unique and corresponds to what looks like an index into a 1D array.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ equivalent of Python's `dict` is `std::map`. To initialize a map using a similar syntax, do this:

```
std::map<int,int> myMap = {{4,3},                       # center  = 3
                           {0,2},{2,2},{6,2},{8,2},     # corners = 2
                           {1,1},{3,1},{5,1},{7,1}};    # sides   = 1
```

Note that this needs C++11.

If you cannot use C++11, turn to [`map_list_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#map_list_of) in Boost.Assign. The example from their page is:

```
using namespace boost::assign; // bring 'map_list_of()' into scope
std::map<int,int> next = map_list_of(1,2)(2,3)(3,4)(4,5)(5,6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although a "language equivalent" might me something like an `std::unordered_map` your use case may be more efficiently served with a straight array:

```
int RANKS[] = {2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2};
```