# Does C++ have a data structure like a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, c++, data-structures, stl

I am new to C++. I use a Python dictionary to store the data previously, now I am working on C++. Does C++ also have a data structure like Python's dictionary?
My scenario is as follows,

We have 4 flows in the network and assign a route to each flow. Thus, in python we can:

```
  dictFlowRoute = {"flow1":(1,2,3,4),  #flow1 is sent by node 1 to node 4.
                   "flow2":(1,5,3,4),
                   "flow3":(1,2,5,3),
                   "flow4":(2,3,1,5)}
```

based on the given route (*dictFlowRoute*), we can know which streams are transmitted by each pair of nodes. *For example, "flow1" and "flow3" are transmitted by node pair (1,2).* In python, we can generate another dictionary to store these data,

```
dictNodePairwithFlow = { (1,2):("flow1","flow3"),
                         (2,3): ("flow1","flow4"),
                         (3,4): ("flow1","flow2"),
                         (1,5): ("flow2", "flow4"),
                         (5,3): ("flow2","flow3")}
```

Hence, in C++, how to present *dictFlowRoute*, and how to generate *dictNodePairwithFlow* according to the given *dictFlowRoute*?

Comment: "Does C++ also have a data structure like Python's dictionary?" Yes: [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Comment: Even if it didn't, it's not that hard to implement yourself.

Comment: For reference, the language-agnostic name of the "dictionary" data structure is a Hash Map.

Comment: @jfaccioni General name for "dictionary" is "associative array". Hash Map is one of implementations of that.

Comment: Also see [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) which differs from std::map primarily in its implementation — it is a hash map, whereas `std::map` is usually a tree. Now that you're a C++ programmer, you get to think a lot about what you want to optimise for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674009/c-equivalent-of-python-dictionaries has an answer or two on this topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ equivalent of Python dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674009/c-equivalent-of-python-dictionaries)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python's `Dictionary` data type is an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). In C++, we have two options to choose from, [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). The main difference is that `std::map` uses a [Self Balancing Red-Black Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) and `std::unordered_map` uses a [Hash Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) implementation. And because of this, `std::unordered_map` is generally faster than `std::map`.

For your case, ill go with `std::unordered_map` to demonstrate. Unlike Python, we don't use `Key:Value` to initialize the map, instead we can use the `[]` operator.

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>    // For the std::unordered_map implementation.
#include <string>    // For the std::string implementation.
...

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::array<int, 4>> dictFlowRoute;
dictFlowRoute["flow1"] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
dictFlowRoute["flow2"] = { 1, 5, 3, 4 };
dictFlowRoute["flow3"] = { 1, 2, 5, 3 };
dictFlowRoute["flow4"] = { 2, 3, 1, 5 };

std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<std::string, std::string>> dictNodePairwithFlow;
dictNodePairwithFlow[std::make_pair(1, 2)] = std::make_pair("flow1", "flow3");
dictNodePairwithFlow[std::make_pair(2, 3)] = std::make_pair("flow1", "flow4");
dictNodePairwithFlow[std::make_pair(3, 4)] = std::make_pair("flow1", "flow2");
dictNodePairwithFlow[std::make_pair(1, 5)] = std::make_pair("flow2", "flow4");
dictNodePairwithFlow[std::make_pair(5, 3)] = std::make_pair("flow2", "flow3");
```

Additional: [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair), [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: std::map doesn't use hashing. It uses only comparison.

Comment: @gerum Sorry I missed it. Thank you for pointing out!