# How to convert a returned Python dictionary to a C++ std::map<string, string>

Tags: python, c++, c++builder

I'm calling Python from C++, and trying to perform some data conversions.

For example, if I call the following Python function

```
def getAMap():
   data = {}
   data["AnItem 1"] = "Item value 1"
   data["AnItem 2"] = "Item value 2"
   return data
```

from C++ as:

```
PyObject *pValue= PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
```

where pFunc is a PyObject* that points to the getAMap python function.
Code for setting up pFunc omitted for clarity.

The returned pointer, pValue is a pointer to a (among other things) Python dictionary.
Question is, how to get thh dictionary into a std::map on the C++ side as smoothly as possible?

I'm using C++ Builder bcc32 compiler that can't handle any fancy template code, like boost python, or C++11 syntax.

(Changed question as the python object is a dictionary, not a tuple)

Comment: Just found a library that *makes it easy to convert Python objects (Python C API) to standard C++ datatypes* as it says [here](https://github.com/dubzzz/Py2Cpp#metaprogramming-serving-py-c-and-c-py). Looks like it might help you due to it also supports `std::map`.

Comment: Also, consider [tag:swig].

Comment: Rob, I'm using swig in fact.

Comment: David; that library looks great, but I can't use it with this compiler unfortunately.

Comment: i would use [PyTuple_GetItem](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/tuple.html) and copy the values into a map. Or write a swig typemap that does it for you.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I'm new to swig and embedding of Python. I guess a typemap would do it, so looking into that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842941/translating-python-dictionary-to-c

Comment: This question is linked to a question related to translating Python code for populating a dictionary, to C++. That is quite different from this question. Not sure why it was linked??

Comment: @TotteKarlsson The library actually is just one header file. If I didn't miss anything the `std::map` casting is no longer than about 100 lines of code. So maybe you can just use the concept of the library and adapt it for your compiler?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty ugly, but I came up with this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> my_map;

// Python Dictionary object
PyObject *pDict = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);

// Both are Python List objects
PyObject *pKeys = PyDict_Keys(pDict);
PyObject *pValues = PyDict_Values(pDict);

for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < PyDict_Size(pDict); ++i) {
    // PyString_AsString returns a char*
    my_map.insert( std::pair<std::string, std::string>(
            *PyString_AsString( PyList_GetItem(pKeys,   i) ),
            *PyString_AsString( PyList_GetItem(pValues, i) ) );
}
```