# Creating a C++ object in Python, and handing its pointer back to C++?

Tags: python, c++, swig, c++builder

I have successfully wrapped a C++ class,  MyObject to Python using Swig.

```
class MyObject()
{
      public: 
        double i;
};
```

A MyObject can be created in Python like this:

```
import MyModule
m = MyModule.MyObject()
```

The important thing about the above lines is that behind the scenes, the MyObject object is created in the pyd module that is created from C++, and "somewhere", there is a **new MyObject()** call, returning a pointer to a MyObject object.

Further, the following Python script has a function that **returns** a Python MyObject, i.e:

```
import MyModule
def getMyObject():
    m = MyModule.MyObject()
    #... do something with m, e.g.
    m.i = 42
    return m
```

My actual use case is that I *initialize the Python interpreter from a C++ application*.

I am executing the Python function above,from within my C++ application, i.e.

```
PyObject *pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
```

where pFunc is a PyObject* that points to the getMyObject() python function. Code for setting up pFunc omitted for clarity. The returned value should hold a pointer to a MyObject "somewhere".

So question is, how, on the C++ side, do I go from the PyObject* pValue to a MyObject* pointer?

I do have a similar question open, see [How to convert a returned Python dictionary to a C++ std::map<string, string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988922/how-to-convert-a-returned-python-dictionary-to-a-c-stdmapstring-string?noredirect=1#comment86996540_49988922), but that question is more complex, as it involve the conversion from a Python dictionary, to a std class (std::map).

Having a user defined type, like MyObject, would perhaps be the first a user would want to learn to exchange. Curiously, I can't find a simple example showing how todo this.

I'm new to Swig but after doing some research it seem likely that one need to create a *typemap*?

Also, I'm using Embarcaderos C++ Builder, and can't use any C++11 and/or boost python libraries.
Any hints?

**Update**
The following code seem to properly unwrap the C++ object pointer:

```
        PyObject* p = python.callFunction(getPluginMetaDataF);
        PyObject* pThis = PyObject_GetAttrString(p, "this"); 
        unsigned long addr = PyLong_AsLong(pThis);
        MyObject* ptr = (MyObject*)(addr);
        cout << ptr->i; //Prints 42!
```

The above code seem to properly access the object. However, the life time of the object seem a little shaky, i.e. when is this object destroyed? After Py_Finalize() ??

Comment: Here you can find an answer to your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040669/how-can-i-implement-a-c-class-in-python-to-be-called-by-c. It does a little more than what you - the class is extended in Python using the director pattern